# Use sed/awk to remove the last portion of a delimited-text column

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with rows of values. The first column, a PacBio read ID, is a forward-slash-delimited value. I would like to modify the column by removing the final slash and values beyond it. Ideally the result would be stream-able (sed/awk, etc.) and would not rely on the number of forward slashes (i.e. the solution should work whether there is a single forward slash, or three, as below.)

```
# example row
m54151_170617_100137/4194626/10117_11723/0_1606 1257    1606

# desired row
m54151_170617_100137/4194626/10117_11723    1257    1606
```

Comment: Are those tabs between your values or something else?

Comment: @EdMorton those are tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short ***sed*** solution:

```
sed 's~/[^/[:space:]]* ~ ~' file
```

The exemplary output:

```
m54151_170617_100137/4194626/10117_11723 1257    1606
```

---

- `~` - treated as *sed* subcommand separator

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind slightly modifying the whitespace:

```
awk '{sub("/[^/]*$","",$1)}1' input
```

If whitespace matters:

```
sed 's@^\([^ ]*\)/[^ /]* @\1 @' input
```

Comment: excellent answer. I gave Roman the check though as I think its a bit more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

If you potentially have spaces in your fields, use the `/` to split.

With awk you can split on `/`, rejoin the fields with `/` then print the last field:

```
$ awk -F'/' '{s=""
             for (i=1;i<NF;i++)
                s=s ? s FS $i : $i
              print s $NF}' file
```

The same is a bit easier in Ruby:

```
$ ruby -F'/' -lane 'puts $F[0...-1].join("/")<<$F[-1]' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print substr($1,1,40),$2,$3}' OFS="\t" file

m54151_170617_100137/4194626/10117_11723    1257    1606
```

Comment: thanks, but this solution requires that you know the substring length so it is not general.